# Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'quantity' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I am trying to create `stored Procedure` in mysql, which insert values into one `table` and update value in another `table`.

But i am getting following error while doing that.

`Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'quantity' in 'field list'`

Pleae help.

Thanx in advance.

Below is my `stored Procedure`:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `billing`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `createBill`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createBill`(x_itemId       VARCHAR(400),x_ItemQnty INT(200),x_totalBill VARCHAR(400))
BEGIN

DECLARE p_bill_Id INT;
DECLARE p_item_qnty INT;

SET p_bill_Id=0;
SET p_item_qnty=0;
SET p_item_qnty = getItemQnty(x_itemId);
SET p_bill_Id=getBillid();

IF p_bill_Id IS NULL THEN
SET p_bill_Id=0;
END IF;

IF p_item_qnty >0 THEN

INSERT INTO bill_details (billId, itemId, itemQuantity, totalBill)
VALUES (p_bill_Id,x_itemId,x_ItemQnty,x_totalBill); 
SET p_item_qnty=p_item_qnty-1;
UPDATE billing.item_details SET item_details.item_quantity = p_item_qnty WHERE item_details.item_id = x_itemId;
SELECT CONCAT(x_itemId," added successfully") AS 'message';
ELSE 
SELECT CONCAT(x_itemId," is finsihed") AS 'message';
END IF;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Error does not seem to be on the SP. Was it while creating SP or calling SP? If calling, post the code that calls SP.

Comment: this error was coming while creating SP.

Comment: It seems that you have 2 functions defined `'getItemQnty'` and `'getBillid'`. Said error must be from them. Edit and post their code in your question.

Comment: Thanx. i was facing error in function. thanx a ton. :)